# Existence of a vector field with a finite number of limit cycles.

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, differential-topology, limit-cycles

The following question is related to the Seifert conjecture.

Let $M$ be a closed manifold with zero Euler characteristic. Is it true that each homotopy class of nowhere-zero vector fields on $M$ contains a vector field with a finite number of (stable) limit cycles (closed trajectories)? Is it easy to construct?

Comment: And you would like to allow periodic orbits that are not stable limit cycles?

Comment: I would guess that the suspension of an Anosov diffeomorphism of the two torus is a counterexample, but I am not so sure now. 

Comment: I would like that every closed trajectory is non-degenerate. But if it is more easier to construct a field without that restriction it would be also interesting.

Comment: @rpotri There is a vector field on 3-torus with non-zero first coordinate and finite number of closed orbits. It seems it is a counterexample to your idea. 

Comment: In that case, it is the suspension of something isotopic to the identity, so it is homotopic to a suspension of a Morse-Smale diffeomorphisms in the torus. The suspension of the Anosov is not the 3-torus. You want finitely many closed orbits or finitely many which are stable?, I guess that in the latter case that should be true.  

Comment: It still not clear to me if you want to allow non-degenerate unstable orbits.

Comment: I want a vector field with finitely many closed trajectories (and each of them is non-degenerate). 

Comment: What about no periodic orbit at all ? It seems that K. Kuperberg's construction of counterexamples to Seifert conjecture doesn't change homotopy class, but I may be wrong. Here is the address
http://www.jstor.org/stable/2118623

Comment: I am not a specialist, but I recon, that the  proof of Seifert conjecture, mentioned in the question, starts with a vector field with a finite number of closed orbits. Taken such a field one apply "plugs". So my question was how to construct a vector field for the first step of the proof, is it possible to do in a given homotopy class?

I will check the rpotrie's reference, It seems it answer my question. 

Comment: To get finitely many closed orbits, a finite number of "Wilson plugs"(Annals 1966) is enough : any orbit entering the plug is attracted to one of the two periodic orbits inside the plug, if it enters at a point in a certain "entry region" of the plug (with non-empty interior), and otherwise the orbit is "unchanged" : it re-emerges at the same point as before plugging. Now, by compactness, a finite number of annuli transverse to the flow suffice to meet all orbits. Thickening them a little and replacing by plugs gives you finitely many closed orbits. And the homotopy class is unchanged.

Comment: Nice! So it is a construction I was looking for modulo "Wilson plug does not change the homotopy class". Could you, please, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

In any dimension bigger or equal to $4$, the answer is yes. See [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970973).

In dimension 3, the question is adressed [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01388724)*. In fact, in this paper neccessary and sufficient conditions to be homotopic to a non singular Morse-Smale flow are given. Morse-Smale means to have finitely many non degenerate closed orbits and that those are al the non-wandering set. In dimension 3 there are restrictions to satisfy that property, however, [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970458) proves that one has in the homotopy class vector fields whose minimal sets consist of finitely many periodic orbits (maybe degenerate).

*The reference is K. Yano, The homotopy class of non-singular Morse-Smale vector fields on 3-manifolds, Inventiones Math. (1985).